# SQL procedure where clause to list records

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that will query and return records based on if items are available or not. That part is easy, Im simply passing in a variable to check where available is yes or no. 
But what I want to know is how do I throw a everything clause in there (i.e available, not available, or everything)?

The where clause right now is

```
where availability = @availability
```

The values of availabitility are either 1 or 0, nothing else.

Comment: Are you asking how do you retrieve all the records? Then just leave off the where clause altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NULL to represent everything.

```
WHERE (@availability IS NULL OR availability = @availability)
```

Comment: so this brings back both where availabitility = @availability and everything else correct

Comment: Correct, if @availability is NULL, then everything is returned.  If @availability is not NULL, then only records with the matching availability are returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   @availability IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   availability = @availability
```

Passing a `NULL` value will select everything.

This query will use an index on `availability` if any.

Answer (score 0):

multiple ways of doing it. Simpliest way is is to set the default value of the @availability to null and then your where clause would look like this

```
WHERE (@availability IS NULL OR availability = @availability)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the type of @availability, but assuming -1 = everything then you could simply do a

```
where @availability = -1 OR availability = @availability
```

Comment: Availability is either 1 or 0, how would I jsut bring back everything if the user wants to see all of them